# Eclipse C/C++ HelloWorld

Tags: eclipse-cdt

After I had some problems with a c++ program in Eclipse Juno I decided to start it over and I've created a HelloWorld program.It builds but when I press the Run button nothing happens.The odd thing is that I created a few weeks ago a small C application that worked like it should and my next task is to create a c++ application but if the simple HW isn't working I don't think that something bigger will work.Any suggestions of what should I do?
This is the HW code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.I needed to append the path to the builder
System-Advanced system settings->hardware->environment variables and in the first table I created the new path and in the bottom table i've appended the same path to the Path variable.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code . If it doesnt work, try removing the namespace to run[dnt forget to recomplie]

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
   cout << "Hello World!";
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope,that gives me an error,if the header was wrong,probably I would've got something like "what's cout?"

Comment: @Matt I have modified my answer. pls check

Comment: Error,he doesn't know what `getchar()` is.I've included `cstdio`,no error but the program does nothing.